# C# How can I clear textbox value using selenium driver?

Tags: c#, selenium

**i need clear value "KKKK" then give value "UUUU",How can i do?**

Html sample:

```
<td clospan="2" id="text"> == $0
>input type="tttt" name="YYYY" Value="KKKK" onkeydown="srch_complex(0)" 
size="25">
<a hrer="javescript:srch_CCCC(1)"Query</a>
</td>
```

I try the following method,but still can not.

1.

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("a[href='javescript:srch_CCCC(1)']"));
element.Clear();
element.SendKeys("UUUU");
```

2.

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.ID("text"));
element.Clear();
element.SendKeys("UUUU");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using locators for other elements. If `name="YYYY"` is unique use

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("YYYY"));
```

And if not

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#text > input"));
```

Comment: I use the first method you provided. i need input vaule to textbox,but i use element.sendkeys("UUU") invalid ,how can i do?

Comment: @JiaoJiaoHuang I'm not sure I understand. You have a problem in the line `element.sendkeys("UUU")` or in some other place? and what is the error message?

Comment: my code write :
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("YYYY"));
element.Clear();
The above is true.
next write:
element.sendkeys("UUU");
This time webpage textbox notshown UUU,I don't know where the error.

Comment: @JiaoJiaoHuang Are there more elements with `name="YYYY"`? you can also try the second line.